# In listview creating a making a dynamic changes in layout doesn't working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

In my project, there is ListView inside the listview row item view there is relativeLayout, which position changes dynamically according to the available component on its right side ...

My problem is that first time when listview loaded its looks perfect as I scroll the listview it goes to its right , I have no clue, why its  happening? 
My code is as below:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)holder.relLayout.getLayoutParams();
                if(holder.weekOfYear.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    if(holder.moonImage.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
                    {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,R.id.moon_image);

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF , weekOfYear);

                }
                holder.relLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the ListView's recycling property. You need to reset the position of your view each time. Try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)holder.relLayout.getLayoutParams();
            if(holder.weekOfYear.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
            {
                if(holder.moonImage.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

                }
                else
                {
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,R.id.moon_image);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF , weekOfYear);

            }
            holder.relLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```